# Define a restrictive set for inserts into a column

Tags: mysql, sql

My table on my mysql-server contains a column that acts as a keyword for a filter mechanism on the website I am working on. The entries will be filled by some other people and I dont want to have entries with possible typos in there, because that would mess up the filter. So I want to make it foolproof and restrict the possible inputs into that column to a defined set.

I kind of remember that this could be easily defined somewhere, but I dont know how anymore.
Could someone give me a hint?

Big thanks!
Yannic

Comment: Thanks for looking! Found a solution myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367063/how-to-restrict-a-column-value-in-sqlite-mysql

Comment: Thanks Michael, that was what I was looking for. I found it in the meantime though ^^

Comment: Note that if `sql_mode` is not set to STRICT, MySQL won't actually error on values inserted which aren't in the ENUM list. Enabling strict mode will cause it to outright reject bad values with an error. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: Thanks for the note, I may need that hint...^^