# How to restrict user to input values within a range?

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL, I want to restrict the row to only accept values from 1 to 1000 (inclusive)

```
CREATE TABLE Company(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(100),
    Employees int
);
```

this is the table and I need to restrict the ID row to only have values between 1 to 1000.

I have referred [Want to restrict the value of a MySQL field to specific range (Decimal values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575604/want-to-restrict-the-value-of-a-mysql-field-to-specific-range-decimal-values) and [How to restrict a column value in SQLite / MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367063/how-to-restrict-a-column-value-in-sqlite-mysql) all are kinda old!

I need an updated solution. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MySQL 8.0 you can use CHECK constraint in table creation statement like:

```
CREATE TABLE Company (
  ID int NOT NULL  CHECK (ID BETWEEN 1 AND 1000), 
  Name varchar(100), 
  Employees int
);
```

Test it on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=1ee8124c62b007cfb6688a24df135eb9&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)